# java process multiple string arguments

Tags: java

I have the following code in java:

```
public void loadFiles(String file_1, String file_2) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String line_file1;
    String line_file2;
    BufferedReader buf_file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file_1)));
    BufferedReader buf_file2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file_2)));

}
```

Now when he runs this process, he expects both a file_1 and file_2. But I also want to make it go through when there is only a file_1. How should I specify this?

Comment: public void loadFiles(String... files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use varargs :

```
public void loadFiles(String... fileNames) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader[] buf_file = new BufferedReader[fileNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        buf_file[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileNames[i])));
    }
}
```

Which allows your method to be called with any number of file names :

```
loadFiles("a.txt");
loadFiles("a.txt", "b.txt");
...
```

No need for unnecessary method overloading when there's a simple alternative.

Comment: Mhm, I don't understand. I should then nowhere specify 'file_1' and 'file_2'? I will make an edit to the original post, to clarify the situation better

Comment: @user1987607 Instead of `file_1` and `file_2`, you have `fileNames[0]`, `fileName[1]`, etc... (which you can iterate over in a loop, as shown in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support default values to arguments or skipping the arguments . 
This is exactly where overloading comes into picture

define another method

```
public void loadFiles(String file_1) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran), "..." (Spread operator accepts 'n' arguments). This is kind of similar to list of array arguments (E.g., main(String args[])). Spread operator(...) has been introduced in Java 8. However, for your better understanding a simple example demonstrating the '...' spread operator as below

```
public class TestClass {

public static void test(String... args){
    for(String str: args){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    test("a","m","a", "r");
}
```

}